# titanium mobile: get row title in android issue

Tags: tableview, titanium-mobile

Hello friends,

I am developing an app in Titanium and I have a tableview with display data and on click on row I got row title successfully in iPhone and its work fine but in Android I can't get row title so please give me idea.

```
friendTableView.addEventListener('click',function(e)
{
    if(e.row)
    {
        alert(e.rowData.mobileNo);
        var mobileNo = e.rowData.mobileNo;
        alert(mobileNo);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No its give me blank and please online in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7529/discussion-between-muhammad-zeeshan-and-nikunj-r-jadav

Comment: plz online in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7529/discussion-between-muhammad-zeeshan-and-nikunj-r-jadav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my issue:

```
          var mobileNo = e.row.mobileNo;
          alert(mobileNo);

          instead of

          var mobileNo = e.rowData.mobileNo;
          alert(mobileNo);
```

and its work fine.

Comment: If you replace if(e.row) with if(e.rowData), then the old code works?

Answer (score 0):

Appcelerator behaves differently in iOS and Android regarding the clicked row.

While iOS will work ok with "rowData" as code submitted by the original question but will raise an error with Android. While using "row" only as replied